# Blocked after being unblocked

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

This is an old account of mine and I was blocked from asking on Stack Overflow a long time ago. Today, I signed in and I wasn't expecting that my account was unblocked. I wrote a test question, and was completely surprised that it was posted.

Members of the community rained downvotes on me and now I'm blocked again. It was only a test...why did I get this? Then another user visited my profile and downvoted one of my rusty questions.

Will I be blocked permanently from asking?

Comment: The now-deleted "test question": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594847/am-i-blocked-from-asking

Comment: @Nuser What did you expect to achieve for your silly and meaningless test post. You should have immediately removed this after posting.

Comment: You really choose all the major tags, with the most active and experienced users, what did you expect to happen? That your post went unnoticed?

Comment: Do I agree with such a quick reaction? meh. Does it suck? 100%. Is it your fault? Yes. You had no reason to ask this. If you had no question to ask, why did have to test? (If you say "old account", I assume you have another newer account that can post) If you had a question... why not post that instead?

Comment: Fairly stunning.  Just ask your Mom what happens when you litter a public place and leave your name on it.  Albeit that if she's anything like my Mom, you do risk a good smack over the head for being so insensitive *and* dense.

Comment: From now on we should call blocking bot/script "inspiration struck again" ! :)

Comment: good grief... **Read the message the system prints at you when you're blocked!** It tells you both why and for how long. You even got a warning *on the page where you composed this fake question* telling you that if it wasn't well-received you'd probably be blocked - how on earth can we possibly make this any easier?

Comment: @Shog9 ,from what i recall,the warning is sometimes superfluous and after you click post,A _message_ prints "_we are no longer accepting questions from this account_".

Comment: Screenshot, please - there should be a LOT more on that page.

Comment: "It was just a prank bro! Just a prank" - well. SO can't know. SO won't assume. And you _could_ be more careful.

Answer (score 16):

You're asking why you were downvoted for posting a bad question?  You were downvoted for posting a bad question.  You should have posted a good question if you want it to be received well.

Answer (score 11):

It used to be that question bans were permanent. Recently this was changed; they now last 6 months.
However, if the first question you post is received poorly, you will be banned again.

(From the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

You considered your new question a test, but the system did not. The system assumes that all questions are in earnest.

You'll have to wait another 6 months. The best thing to do, is to use that time to learn about asking. Jon Skeet himself wrote a good piece about asking questions on SO, ["Writing the perfect question"](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints). It may not be very useful for you right now, but it will be in 6 months.

Comment: 6 months for asking again? That's disgusting....since when the human being need all that time to learn such a simple thing,to ask a good question?

Comment: Stack Overflow receives a lot of bad questions every day. The 6 month period is meant to stop people who have a history of asking poorly received questions. The fact that you can use that time to learn, is more of a side effect.

Comment: @Nuser well, aparrently, from your behaviour, longer than six months, (unless you are not human?).

Comment: Is there a way for people to tell if their question ban is over other than trying to ask another question?

Comment: @Nuser The ban is not about *you*, it's about the *site*. The site is flooded with so many bad questions that it's about to implode. And you are contributing to that. So people who ask bad questions get throttled to once every 6 months until they can demonstrate that they can ask good questions.

Comment: @Mysticial Well fine.But don't you think 6 month is an astronomical number to contain the flood?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm pretty sure the answer to that question is "no". But I'd need to find a reference to back that up.

Comment: @Nuser No. 6 months is not too long when you consider that the number of bad question askers probably outnumber the answerers by at least 1000 to 1. In short, the situation is so bad that it is by-design that the site tries to get rid of those who can't ask good questions as they suck up valuable time from those who could be focusing on good questions that deserve to be answered.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The only way to know if you are banned or not is to try.  There have been request to change that

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! It seems like if the ban was indicated after clicking "ask question" rather than "post question" it would help prevent this type of thing, although I don't know how often people ask a "test question" like this, or how difficult it would be to change that, so maybe it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Don'tPanic No problem.  The only reason I would like to be forewarned is so if I spend a lot of time making a great post and then I find out I am still blocked it would be a waste of my time.  If I could find out first them I save that time.  Although the obvious solution is just don't ask bad questions ;)

Comment: The ban *is* indicated after clicking "ask question", @Don'tPanic.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the clarification. Sorry for that tangent, then.