# Does the 1 question 6 months after last question for question ban recur?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I am question banned. I have been trying to straighten my account but too many questions are outdated as well as deleted and fixable.

Reference: [Attempt to understand ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341055/is-there-a-better-mediation-method-to-help-lift-their-question-ban)

I am not sure how deep in I am so I feel as though my only way to get out is to fix people's questions and answer questions from my limited knowledge.

In looking to fix my account again for the 5th time I have been rereading this over and over from the description page of the ban:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

Does this mean 6 months after your last question you get to post a good one and if it gets upvoted you get to continue or does it have to not get any downvotes? If it is downvoted do you have to wait again for 6 months or is that it, you can never post a question again?

Looking into my account, my last question was in 2015 and I have not been able to post another. Is my account completely shot now? Also does this calculation reach across all of Stack Exchange or just each sub-stack at a time? My previous question in meta was downvoted 5 times (why I don't understand) and this one will probably be too, but does this also work negatively toward my status?

Not being able to see how bad the ban against the account is, is very frustrating and makes it seem hopeless to get it unbanned. Especially for those not technically savvy or unable to answer a lot of the other questions posted to this site.

I am asking these questions to better understand the ban system and when (if at all) I would be able to ask another question. I have positive rep on multiple other stacks except this one and I find this one helps me the a lot and I would like to contribute with better questions.

Comment: *"Does this mean 6 months after your last question you get to post a good one and if it gets upvoted you get to continue"* it depends on how deep in the hole you are. If you've repeatedly asked poorly received questions after a 6 month ban, it may take several good ones to get back out of it. And, no, meta doesn't affect your SO question ban.

Comment: @KevinB So that means you get to ask another one in another 6 months if it isn't upvote or downvoted? That means SO is purposely making it those who are trapped in the ban wait years before their account is recitified? Doesn't that leave their fate to all other users? Does that mean anyone that a specific user doesn't like can downvote all their questions to get them banned? How can you tell how deep your ban is? So this means I have YEARS till I can be positive again? It has been 2 years for me already and I haven't had a chance to ask another one. I should have been able to ask 4 by now.

Comment: @JukEboX all of that info you ask for (or a lot of it at least) is in the meta post about bans.... But: yes you have to wait 6 months in between questions. No you cannot know how deep in you are. You can (and SHOULD) fix your questions that are visible to get extra votes on them. Most of the work you do on the site that ISN'T fixing your Qs and getting more upvotes on them doesn't help your Q-ban. Lastly if someone goes and downvotes all your content, that'll likely be reversed.

Comment: @Patrice I have fixed my questions and downvotes do not go away. I have gone over them multiple times and can't edit them anymore. Even used the guide on how to write a good question. Any why have I been unable to post a new question 6 months after my last question. It has been 2 years and I haven't been able to post anything.

Comment: @yellowantphil there isn't because I have been reading about the question ban for weeks now and these questions haven't been answered and the ban is still unclear to me unless these question are answered. The Meta and How-To do not provide enough information and in my view should be updated with more information as well as better links and references should be made.

Comment: @jukebox no clue why in this specific instance you cannot.... Maybe a mod can answer that. And I do sympathize about the situation you are in. I am just giving the steps you can take to try and get out of it, and pointing out what is likely not helping your case (answers and edits, while awesome, will not do much here :/)

Comment: @yellowantphil actually it was mentioned in pretty much these exact words (6 months rate limit) on a thread here earlier this week....  But IIRC the post has jow been deleted (or I can't remember correctly and can't find it anymore )

Comment: You asked two questions on Oct 28th... (which look fairly like the same question twice) - one got a downvote and you deleted both questions. So that wouldn't have done you any favours. Probably best to include full error messages in the post as you appear to have not done that which tends to attract downvotes. Looks like you may have got an upvote or something somewhere as your account is no longer Q-banned. Make sure your next question counts as at this stage it'll be easy to fall back to the 6 month ban if it's poorly received.

Comment: *"looking to fix my account again for the 5th time"* Seriously, 5 times you've been banned? Wow...

Comment: I would suggest on your next question that you only ask it when you have literally done everything else. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). I appreciate my comment doesn't help you in your current situation but thought it would help if and when you do get round to being able to ask a new question. It's good to see that you are trying.

Comment: Not sure if it qualifies as a dupe but [here is the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324318/4342498)

Comment: @Patrice thanks for the information. I thought I read that editing questions and answers would help but now it seems it doesn't. I have been told 2 conflicting answers.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the information. nothing showed up on my deleted questions either. I am not sure if that is a bug or not.

Comment: @DavidG no I have tried editing and updating my questions 5 times to get the account on top again.

Comment: @Bugs thanks for the reference. It will help when I go back to coding again when I have another question. I have been practicing asking better questions on the other STACKs such as SU and SF.

Comment: Someone here should write up an answer.

Comment: Not sure it would apply to any of your questions, but I wrote up [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) post to help people that ask requirements-only questions.

Comment: As an avid Googler, I answer most of my questions on my own. You know, the questions that would be answerable here and possibly give me up votes. The questions I end up asking are near impossible to answer so they just sit there. Most of the answers I get are wrong or don't work and then I get a down vote by the person answering. What's worse is when I get edited and the context of the question changes making a bad answer correct. It's frustrating. Which has made me better at solving my own problems. Sometimes I'll post a question and answer. If unchallenged, I get points.

Comment: I learnt it hard way, just answer question here, and do your reading from somewhere else only specialised question should be asked here ,and you can ask your doubts in chat.stackoverflow.com and also find best source to learn something.You should understand this is not site that teaches you from scratch it is a repo of High quality questions and specific problem that you are stuck on. I hope you have a good journey.

Comment: @Kayot That is *so very* in line with my experiences as well. I also learned the hard way not to ask a question here on meta insinuating (as you have in that comment) that I know the reasons for any of the downvotes I've received: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342329/1858225

Comment: OP: one thing I notice, looking at your questions, is that in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13725173/1858225), you have HTML elements (`<br />`) that garble your answer because you're not using backticks (`) to prevent them from getting rendered as actual HTML stuff. Make sure to read the rendered version of your question (i.e. by hitting "preview" before posting) to make sure it's actually readable.

Comment: @KyleStrand Syntax on SE has changed around on SE a lot and if you don't use SE a lot I think you fall behind. Back in '12 I was still learning the mark up for SE and that was never conveyed to me. I have been using the preview section a lot more lately and making sure questions are a lot clearer.

Comment: Fair enough. I fixed up that particular question to make sure the `<br />`'s show up.

Comment: I believe there's also a ban for deleting a great deal of one's questions...? Supposedly to prevent users from deleting their own questions once they have gotten the answer they needed or something like that. Not sure if this is relevant here, but I don't think deleting a high number of your own questions is a good idea.

Answer (score 22):

Your chance to ask a new question after 6 months is *not* an ultimatum. It's not a last stand to either get out of the block or die trying. It should be looked at as a rate limit. *Until* you dig yourself out of the block, you are limited to one new question every 6 months.

That one question *could* get you out of the block if it gets upvotes, or it could not be enough to dig you all the way out and you have to wait another 6 months. If it gets downvoted, you'll only dig the hole deeper, but you'll still be able to try again in 6 months. *Most* users do not dig themselves into holes deep enough that one new question can't get them out of it. If your question history is so bad that it will take you years to get out of it using this method, then you really should consider finding ways to improve your past questions instead.

Also keep in mind that deleted questions are still counted towards the timeframe for this 6-month check.

Comment: As stated before many past questions maybe GREATLY outdated as well as deleted and reformatting them would be useless as they would not get any upvotes. Especially in specific cases of outdated code and outdated code standards. And it also seems that the only way out is to ask a good question. There seems to be some argument about if editing questions and providing answers also digs you out. I am still waiting for a definitive answer on that question as I have been given 3 different answers and not enough FAQ information.

Answer (score 6):

There are specifics which aren't immediately apparent to you, namely if you have deleted any questions, which do have an impact on your overall question quality.  Deleting a question in and of itself doesn't hurt you, but if it had a negative score, then it's not in a possible state for you to improve.

That stated, it is perfectly possible to dip into negative favor with the system by asking a poorly received question.  All bans are taken at face value, with all of the data present, in visible or deleted questions.  I don't believe that question bans persist across networks, but I could be wrong - namely in the scenario of cross-site spammers; y'know, the *really* nefarious folk we don't want here.

Taking the time to improve how you ask questions is a good thing; please keep it up.  I'd rather you be able to participate after learning from your mistakes a bit more effectively, than not at all.

Comment: Hm, this all seems to be pretty straightforward, not opinion-based, and (AFAIK) true. Would any downvoters like to explain what's wrong with this answer...?